# Equal partial sums of $k$ numbers of $1$ to $k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are two sequences of $k$ numbers, denoted as $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$, $i\in [1,k]$. Each number is between $1$ and $k$, namely $a_{i}\in [1,k]$, $b_{i}\in [1,k]$, $\forall i\in [1,k]$. Prove that you can always find $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$, such that $1\leq p \leq q\leq k$, $1\leq r \leq s\leq k$, and $$\sum_{i=p}^{q}a_{i}=\sum_{i=r}^{s}b_{i}.$$

Note that the numbers in the sequences are just random integers in the specified range. It is not sorted.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I just don't know how to solve this problem. I don't have any thoughts.

Comment: Even the special case when all the $b_i$ are equal to $k$ is a little tricky. I can't see a way forward for proving the general case, although it is certainly true for small $k$. Where did you find this problem?